# Android button background image in java code

Tags: java, android, imagebutton

I have 45 buttons which i have created by loop in java code. Now i need to set and change the background image depending on the user interaction and also need resize the image also depending on the button. It will be help-full for me if i can do everything for an image button in java.

How i can resize the background image of a button in java code.

Comment: Mabey I am not awake here, but what exactly are you asking here?  Perhapse if you post some code showing what you have tried we will be able to help you.

Comment: I need java some code that can add a background image on a button resizing the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to resize an image on basis of the dimension of a Button, use `getHeight()` and `getWidth()` methods to get the size of the button and use following function to resize image for Button:

### Resizing a Bitmap:

```
public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth) {

int width = bm.getWidth();

int height = bm.getHeight();

float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;

float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

// create a matrix for the manipulation

Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

// resize the bit map

matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

// recreate the new Bitmap

Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);

return resizedBitmap;

}
```

---

Now you can use `setBackgroundDrawable()` or `setBackgroundResource()` methods on a Button object to change its **Background Image** and you can resize a Button via `setHeight()` and `setWidth()` methods.
[Reference](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2009/12/25/resizing-a-bitmap/)

Comment: @Sudeepta give it a try and inform me if it worked for you :).

Comment: The image is transference png image. I need to resize it and also set a background color. what will i do now. Any reference or code that can help-full to me.

Comment: I think you are talking about transparent image. Say you have an image namely tree.png in your drawable folder. Create a bitmap from it using code: `Bitmap ko = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( getResources(), R.drawable.tree);`. Then pass this image to the function above in answer with corresponding button sizes. Say, returned bitmap name is  x. Now create a **Drawable** from this bitmap with code ` Drawable d =new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),x);`. Now set this to the Button(say b) using code `  b.setBackgroundDrawable(d);`

Comment: This is what you asked in your question, so accept the answer. Now you are asking more, to set the background color of transparent image. You should ask another question for that, but I'm giving you clue also for that. Use overlay technique. First create a canvas with a picture of the color u want as background and then draw the transparent image on it and use the combined picture as the image background for button.

Comment: background image resizing works fine. But for transference image i have to change the background color. So this is not the good idea.

Comment: @Sudeepta it is **transparent** not  **transference**. BTW `setBackgroundColor()` can be used to change color, from my point of view it is a good approach to create a new bitmap by merging an existing transparent image and another image with background color using **overlay** technique and then use resizing on the final image to be used as the button background.

Answer (score 0):

Store arrays with the images and the data you want to use for each button, and use them while you are looping over the initialization of the ImageButtons.

Post some code for detailed help.

Comment: I need some java code that can add a background image on a button resizing the image.

Comment: Well, start coding then!